# Fusion of elements of order 8 in a finite simple group

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Must a finite group $G$ with an element $x$ of order 8 such that $x^2$ is conjugate to $x^{-2}$ but $x$ is not conjugate to any element of $\{x^3,x^5,x^7\}$ also have a normal subgroup of index 2?

I believe any counterexample $G$ has a Sylow 2-subgroup of order at least 128, and any simple counterexample $G$ has order at least $10^{10}$.

There are plenty of examples of $G$ that do have normal subgroups of index 2, but for every other fusion pattern, I've either found a simple group with that pattern or proved that no group (simple or not) has such a pattern.

The most obvious way for $x^2$ to be conjugate to $x^{-2}$ is if $x$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}$. Indeed if $x^g = x^{-1}$, then $(x^2)^g = (x^g)^2 = (x^{-1})^2 = x^{-2}$ and $x^2$ is inverted by the same conjugation that inverts $x$. Of course if $x^g = x^3$, then $(x^2)^g = (x^g)^2 = (x^3)^2 = x^6 = x^{-2}$ works as well. 5 is somewhat irrelevant:  if $x^g = x^5$ then $(x^2)^g = (x^g)^2 = (x^5)^2 = x^{10} = x^2$.

The simple groups ${}^2F_4(2)'$ and ${}^2F_4(8)$ both have $x$ conjugate to $x^5$ and $x^2$ conjugate to $x^{-2}$ (where the conjugating elements of course differ for $x$ and $x^2$) without having $x$ conjugate to $x^3$ or $x^7$.

The other patterns are more common:

- $\newcommand{\PSL}{\operatorname{PSL}}\PSL(2,17)$ has $x \sim x^{-1}$ (and so $x^2 \sim x^{-2}$) but $x^3 \not\sim x \not\sim x^5$.
- $\PSL(3,3)$ has $x \sim x^3$ (and so $x^2 \sim (x^2)^3=x^{-2}$) but $x^{-1} \not\sim x \not\sim x^5$.
- $\PSL(3,5)$ has $x \sim x^5$ but $x^3 \not\sim x \not\sim x^{-1}$ and $x^2 \not\sim x^{-2}$
- $M_{12}$ has $x \sim x^{-1} \sim x^3 \sim x^5$ and $x^2 \sim x^{-2}$

Or impossible:

- If $x \sim x^3 \sim x^5$ then $x \sim (x^3) \sim (x^3)^5 = x^7$ and similarly for other "two of three" possibilities.

**Edit:** I am happy with any ideas. If you can show $G$ cannot be simple, that is enough. If you can find a $G$ that has no normal subgroups of index 2, that is enough. If you know of any papers that have techniques that might work, that would also be wonderful.

Comment: Ideally I'd like something like the transfer to say such a (possibly non-simple) group has a normal subgroup of index 2. I haven't collected as much evidence for that, and am not sure how to handle this situation since $\langle x \rangle$ is not a Sylow 2-subgroup.

Comment: I checked that transfer into $\langle x \rangle$ (or its normalizer) does not work. Clearly $x^4$ is in $G' \cap P$ for $P$ a Sylow 2-subgroup, but I don't see how to prove $G' \cap P \neq P$ since examples show we may have (all such) $x \in G' \cap P$. I'm not sure what other element to look at.

Comment: Posted on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156682/fusion-pattern-in-a-cyclic-subgroup-of-order-8

Comment: If you have two simple groups $G_1,G_2$ with elements $x_1,x_2$ of order $8$
with $x_i^2 \sim x_i^{-2}$, and $x_1$ conjugate only to $x_1^3$
while $x_2$ is conjugate only with $x_2^5$, then
$(x_1,x_2) \in G_1 \times G_2$ gives an example.
Admittedly $G_1 \times G_2$ is not simple;
still, it does lack index-$2$ subgroups.

Comment: Thanks! That means nothing like transfer will work (assuming there are no simple examples). Most things I know about fusion won't work either (that group is fusion simple).